# As bad as what you did

Tags: grammar

Let's say a footballer messed up a very important game in a league. Then, one of his teammate mock at him and say:

> Don't worry lad, no one can do as bad as what you **did**.

Or

> Don't worry lad, no one can do as bad as what you **had done.**

Are these two, **grammatically correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are both grammatically correct, in some registers of English.

In particular the use of "what" is not generally considered good English in formal or standard English. But is correct in some slang.

The choice of "did" or "had done" may slightly change the meaning, but not the correctness. As there is no reason for the past perfect, the simple past tense is probably better here.

There are layers of irony here. The speaker is telling the footballer "Don't worry" but he means the opposite. As such the formal register of English would be inappropriate. Trying to "correct" the grammar to make it 
fit standard English feels wrong

> Don't worry, lad. There is nobody who can play football as badly as you played today.

For an English learner. You should not use this kind of irony in most situations. Do you know how the person will feel being mocked ironically in this way? An English learner in this situation should stick to simple encouragement:

> Bad luck today. Or: Better luck for the next match.

That, of course, means something completely different.

Comment: Hello Sir, should I omit the 'what' in my sentence? And why?  Do you have any suggestion to improve that?  I really wanted to improve my english aye' kindly help.

Comment: In some slang "what" is used in place of "that". "The cat what just walked in" instead of "The cat that just walked in" But this is non-standard and best avoided.

Comment: Sir, I'd like to ask, since your a Brit, hope you don't mind. If you say hello, and this is equaled to 'alright' am I correct?. Then, you say hello again for the second time, for example your emailing someone, would you say ''alright again Sir=hello again Sir'' is this possible?

Comment: Yeah I get it. But that's not what I am asking... oh well... thx anyway.